# tdyn/html type browser can't interpret

Tags: browser, nginx, mime-types, policy

I have modified my mime.type and added those type:

```
application/font-woff
application/vnd.ms-fontobject
image/svg+xml
application/font-sfnt
```

The problem is that my content-type return is "tdyn/html" and my browser can't interpret it.
Does the problem come from my nginx server?

Comment: Why you think that problem with nginx? Content type should be `text/html`, may be you mistyped it somewhere?

Comment: Its just hypothesis cause content type should be text/html as you say.

Comment: So, check mime.type file. I guess you accidentally changed content type for html.

Comment: I also have this issue A multi- origin request (Cross -Origin Request) was blocked : the " Same Origin " policy does not refer to the remote resource on http://xxxxxx.fr/extension/webfont/roboto/RobotoCondensed-Regular-webfont.woff. This can be corrected by  moving the resource on the same domain or activating CORS. do you think its reliated

Comment: That's another problem that has nothing to do with topic. Create new post